# how to add new class to Angular JS ng-class with dollar sign?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently joined a team, and they are using AngularJS. Their codes is:

html:

```
<div ng-class="$ctrl.styles.className">I need to add one new class here</div>
```

If I want to put more classes into one div, I can easily make the classes in to an array, like this:

```
<div ng-class="[$ctrl.styles.classNameOne,$ctrl.styles.classNameTwo]"> But how to add the third new class into the array??</div>
```

CSS:

```
.classNameOne {
    position: fixed;       
}
.classNameTwo{
    color:red;
}
```

But how to add more new classes into the array of `div` ? 
I tried many ways, but I don't know how to add new classes into the array of the
    `<div>`, because the class must with the dollar sign: 
    `$ctrl.styles.className`.

Could anyone tell me how to add new classes with dollar signs?

Comment: By the way, it is using Angular JS 1.0

Answer (score 0):

As per the dot notation, `$ctrl.styles.className` should be pointing to a variable `className` inside `styles` object inside your controller referenced by `ctrl`.

So change the value of `className` inside your controller to whatever class that is defined in your CSS file.